# Grammatical correctness of the following sentence

Tags: gerunds, syntactic-analysis, gerund-phrases, participial-phrases

I came across this sentence while preparing for the IELTS writing exam:

> There are a number of causes of people not doing physical activities.

That *causes of* should be followed by a noun or gerund. So does *people not doing physical activities* act as a gerund here?

Could somebody please help me understand it grammatically?

Comment: Is that "number of courses" or "a number of cases"?

Comment: No, *courses of* should be followed by a **noun phrase**, although a gerund phrase does count as one of those. The sentence is somewhat awkward; what task was set for you to solve here for this sentence? Also, the sentence is missing an indefinite article.

Comment: I suspect that should be *courses **for** people.* I think I'd prefer "courses for people which do not involve physical activities", but there isn't really enough information here about what that sentence is actually describing.

Comment: @rajah9 , I have corrected the sentence. It had a spelling mistake. Thanks

Comment: There are many internet examples of an ACC-ing style structure after 'cause of'. The POSS-ing might be preferable on grounds of traditional analysis, but those are shaky grounds.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You do realize, I hope, that our asker will have no idea what you have just done him the honor of indicating.

Comment: @tchrist A person taking IELTS (I've just finished a 1-hour session with one) may well have been schooled in the art of research. An in-house search for the terms I used is not too much to expect from a linguist. / I'd have posted an answer if I'd been able to find a treatment of 'cause of' + 'ACC-ing'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I’ll grant you that it’s certainly easier to find instances with *cases* than it is with *causes*.

Comment: Can you give your source/s for the statement '_causes of_ should be followed by [a] noun or gerund' so that we can look for actual examples, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## “What grammar is this now?”

That grammatical analysis you’ve asked for follows. It’s a clunky sentence, but its parse is not a great mystery. Given:

- There are a number of causes of **people not doing physical activities**.

The portion set in bold is a non-finite clause featuring the *-ing* inflection of the verb.  It is a negated clause whose subject is *people* and whose object is *physical activities*.  This entire verb clause serves as the prepositional object for that sentence’s second instance of *of*.

If instead of using a noun, *people* had been a pronoun standing in for those people, then it would have been in the object form:

- There are a number of causes of **them not doing physical activities**.

If that clause had been in subject position, there would have been some latitude in choosing its head for purposes of verb agreement:

1. People not doing physical activities **are** prone to health problems.
2. People not doing physical activities **is** this country’s most serious health problem.

In the first sentence, the tensed verb *are* is in the plural because it is agreeing with *people*.

In the second sentence, the tensed verb *is* is in the singular because it is agreeing with *(not) doing*.

But I would say that in your sentence, the head is *(not) doing* rather than *people*. That’s because it is not the people themselves whose cause is under discussion, but rather their (not) doing physical activities.

## Analysis via Computational Linguistics

If you run that sentence through [the online Stanford Parser tool](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/), it presents this syntactic analysis:

> #### Your query
>
> *There are a number of causes of people not doing physical activities.*
>
> #### Tagging
>
> There/EX are/VBP a/DT number/NN of/IN causes/NNS of/IN people/NNS not/RB doing/VBG physical/JJ activities/NNS ./.
>
> #### Parse
>
> `(ROOT
>         (S
>           (NP (EX There))
>           (VP (VBP are)
>             (NP
>               (NP (DT a) (NN number))
>               (PP (IN of)
>                 (S
>                   (NP
>                     (NP (NNS causes))
>                     (PP (IN of)
>                       (NP (NNS people))))
>                   (RB not)
>                   (VP (VBG doing)
>                     (NP (JJ physical) (NNS activities)))))))
>           (. .)))`

That’s attaching the very last bit somewhat differently than I might, but it’s interesting to see what the computer thinks of it.  Mine might run more like what they get for *I know three causes of people not doing physical activities*:

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (PRP I))
    (VP (VBP know)
      (NP
        (NP (CD three) (NNS causes))
        (PP (IN of)
          (NP (NNS people)
            (S (RB not)
              (VP (VBG doing)
                (NP (JJ physical) (NNS activities))))))))
    (. .)))
```

That way *people not doing physical activities* is the clause that completes *of*.

## Happier Rewrites

Even though you didn’t ask, there are many other ways to write that sentence if the aim is to make it cleaner. Here are just a few:

- There are several reasons behind people not doing physical activities.
- There are several reasons behind them not doing physical activities.
- There are several reasons behind their not doing physical activities.
- There are several reasons for people not doing physical activities.
- There are several reasons for people’s not doing physical activities.
- There are several reasons for them not doing physical activities.
- There are several reasons for their not doing physical activities.
- There are several reasons why people are not doing physical activities.
- There are several reasons why they are not doing physical activities.

The last pair is the best of the rewrites listed, in my estimation, but certainly others are possible. The possessive choices are highly stylized and seldom encountered in normal conversation.

Comment: I can't accept this. 'People not doing physical activities' are not caused.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don’t understand: what can you “not accept” here? Are you simply saying you dislike the sentence?

Comment: Logically, it's the [people's] not doing physical activities that is caused. As I said in the comment earlier, the POSS-ing structure would seem more  fidelitous. It could be that the (apparently idiomatic) mismatch of the use of the ACC-ing is what is worrying OP.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth We do not know the testing context in which the sentence occurred. The poster asked for help analysing its grammar. Have you another parse in mind? Just read *causes of* as *reasons for*; the grammar is identical.

Comment: I'd say it's extra-grammatical, but (I'm estimating from the number of Google hits, and experience) not unacceptable.

Comment: When linguists find a grammatical construction in common use, they do not pass approval or disapproval of it. That isn’t their job. Rather, they explain how its grammar behaves. Feel free to ask Lawler.

Comment: 'Extra-grammatical' is not 'ungrammatical'. However, Quirk & Svartvik did postulate a five-point 'acceptability' scale.